# A little misunderstanding about this regex pattern

Tags: regex

[image]

Let **H** be column 1, **E** be column 2, **L** column 3, **P** 4

---

I understand where the **H** comes from.

I also see how the **L** works.

But I am a bit confused on **E** and **P**.

If we look horizontally, the regex `HE|LL|0+` only matches `{HE, LL, 0 (1 or more times)}`

The regex `EP|IP|EF` matches `{EP, IP, EF}`

How is it that the string `E` matches **both of these conditions?**

Similarly with `[PLEASE]`, which matches `{P, L, E, A, S, E} (any combination of these letters)`, only matches with `EP` from the vertical regex, then why is there just a `P`?

Am I reading this incorrectly? This was taken from regexcrossword

Comment: Can you share some sample inputs?  The answer may depend on knowing the rules of the crossword, and many people may not be familiar with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the nature of the crossword.

The string `HE` matches `HE|LL|O+`

The string `LP` matches `[PLEASE]+`

The string `HL` matches `[^SPEAK]+`

The string `EP` matches `EP|IF|EF`

Each row and column matches its regex, so the solution is valid.

---

Like, the following statement doesn't make sense...

> How is it that the string E matches both of these conditions?

There is no string `E`.  There are two strings, `HE` and `EP`.

Comment: Ohhhh yes I did misunderstand the nature thank you for clearing this up

Comment: it's the "matrix" or facsimile thereof that doesn't really work here it seems...(at least in the sense that there's no meaning given to a [row,column])